# R - Using purrr to replace NULL elements with NA in a list of lists

Tags: r, list, data-manipulation, purrr

I am trying to replace the NULL elements of the list below with NAs inside a map() before using rbindlist on the cleaned list:

```
m = list(min = list(id = "min", val = NULL), 
     max = list(id = "max", val = 7), 
     split = list(id = "split", val = "gini"))

str(m)
List of 3
 $ min  :List of 2
  ..$ id : chr "min"
  ..$ val: NULL
 $ max  :List of 2
  ..$ id : chr "max"
  ..$ val: num 7
 $ split:List of 2
  ..$ id : chr "split"
  ..$ val: chr "gini"
```

I have tried: `map(m, ~list_modify(.x, new = 8), .default = NA) %>% rbindlist` but I'm not quite sure why the `.default = NA` does not work. From the example in the documentation, I'm guessing it's because `.default = NA` checks for NULLs at the first level of list returned by list_modify? Placing it inside `list_modify()` did not work either. Is there a way to replace the NULLs with NA inside the map pipeline itself without the use of lapply?

Comment: Can `NULL` elements occur at different hierarchy levels of your list? If so, you can use a nested `map`: `map(m, function(x) map(x, function(y) ifelse(is.null(y), NA, y)))`

Comment: Thanks @Maurits, yes they can occur at all levels except the first. I just need to replace the NULLs at the second level in order to use rbindlist (since the NULL elements have 0 length and non-NULL have length 1). Is the nested map supposed to work on deeper levels?

Comment: Sorry I realise that I didn't make myself very clear in my the comment; `map(m, function(x) map(x, function(y) ifelse(is.null(y), NA, y)))` will only replace `NULL` entries at the second level, so this should work in your case.

Answer (score 5):

Using `purrr::map_depth`, you can specify the depth at which values are to be replacd:

```r
m = list(min = list(id = "min", val = NULL), 
         max = list(id = "max", val = 7), 
         split = list(id = "split", val = "gini"))

res <- purrr::map_depth(m, 2, ~ifelse(is.null(.x), NA, .x) )
str(res)
#> List of 3
#>  $ min  :List of 2
#>   ..$ id : chr "min"
#>   ..$ val: logi NA
#>  $ max  :List of 2
#>   ..$ id : chr "max"
#>   ..$ val: num 7
#>  $ split:List of 2
#>   ..$ id : chr "split"
#>   ..$ val: chr "gini"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>